# Cocos2d. Sprite and progress bar tight connection

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Start to learning Cocos2d and have a question. With moving of the sprite I need  progress (health) bar keep moving with them (slightly above the sprite), with keeping it position relative to the sprite like if it was one sprite. Any ideas how to realise?

Thanks, 
Alex.

Comment: Do it in your game loop. Just position the Y position with an offset above the sprites head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the health bar as a child to the sprite, at the required offset from the soldier's body. When you later move the soldier, the health bar will follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the health bar sprite as a child of the other sprite:

```
[sprite addChild:healthBar];
```

You can position the health bar sprite as usual, but the final position will be relative to the parent's anchor point (which by default is located at the center of the sprite).